# Google Maps GeoCode API returning NO_RESULTS for search by PostalCode without specifying the region/country

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Using Google Maps Geocode API - which returns LAT LON and other details based upon an address search. I am searching by only the postalCode because that is the only thing I know. I input a Tokyo postal Code `1900100`, however, it returns no results:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:1900100&key=myKey`

Yet when I specify the region then it does return results. How do I get results when I do not know the region ahead of time?

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:1900100&key=myKey&region=jp`

---

However, this issue isn't present for EVERY postal code. The following query with postal code `876-0854` does return result for the location in Japan, even tho the region is not specified

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:8760854&key=myKey`

Comment: It could be a case where, without the "-" or the region, the postal code is considered ambiguous and provides no results. For example with 1900100, it could be 1900-100 (Lisboa, Portugal) or it could be 190-0100 (Ikanikeisaiganaibaai Tokyo To). It may be worth passing the code into [Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) prior to geocoding the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:1900100&key=myKey returns no result because it is too ambiguous without region biasing or viewport.

For your second query, it returned a result because adding a region bias will narrow your search. It is also recommended that you use correct and properly formatted address in your Geocoding requests.

A same scenario was also reported in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863#comment5). You can star the issue to receive updates.